# SignalR .Net client cannot connect with https

Tags: signalr.client

I am using SignalR Core 2.4.1.0.

This is an Owin project, self-hosted.

My configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Incoming: {ctx.Request.Path}");
           await next();
        });
        
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

        app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);

    }
```

I am able to connect to https://localhost:9999/signalr/hubs from a web browser fine.

I am also able to connect to SignalR when not using https. (after removing the urlacl )

I also have tried adding a middleware before the SignalR to see the incoming request.

With http the middleware shows the Request and path.

With https the middleware shows the Request from the web browser but never shows any request from the client.

The client just changes states from connecting to disconnected with not exceptions.

My client for testing is .Net console application:

```
var hub = new HubConnection("https://localhost:9999");
            
            var hubProxy = hub.CreateHubProxy("MyHUB");
            

            hub.Error += (e) =>
            {

            };

            hub.StateChanged += (s) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.NewState.ToString());
            };

            hub.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I've used SignalR before but this is my first time trying to implement ssl.

In summary, .Net client will connect via http but not https.
Browser can connect to the JS library over https but I haven't tried using the JS library yet.

T.I.A.

Comment: I should also note that I'm using a self-signed certificate for testing.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding certificate to the Trusted Root and by replacing the URL with the name of my desktop  instead of localhost.

Comment: You have some issues with websocket configuration in your server. SignalR needs a working websocket, and those are prone to breakage in misconfigured tls and reverse proxy scenarios.